# Database architecture customer management

Tags: architecture, uml, software-design

I have developed a working mvc asp.net application (using EF).
I have a Database Table Customer with relationship to Person table
Person table has a field AdditionalContactInfo and Demographics

A new feature to implement issome kind of marketing system with Leads and Prospects.

My question : 
- Do i put Leads and Prospect in the Customer Table and use a flag for CustomerType or is it better to create two new Tables Leads and Prospects?

- In case of second option how to convert lead/prospect to customer

Maybe there's a better option i didn't thought of.
Some UML or database diagrams of customer management would also be great

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to avoid optional fields and type codes used to determine when to use them. This leads to mistakes and different interpretations. (E.g., in program code for reports vs. creation vs. updating.)

Define the terms in the business domain precisely. When does a Lead become a Customer? When a purchase is made? Can a Person play the role of a Customer for one Product while playing the role of a Lead you're chasing for another bigger Product? That would imply each role should be a separate table. If you mash them into one table with optional values and type codes, adding features later will be harder, besides the perennial problems associated with null values.

Comment: Good point about the different roles that a single customer instance could play.

Answer (score 0):

From what you're describing here, you don't need to put Leads and Prospects in separate tables.  Whether a customer has done business with you or not is an attribute of the Customer entity.  So yes, put a field in the Customer table for CustomerType or whatever.  (However, it isn't a "flag": a flag is an attribute that is either true or false.)

You'll have some sort of other table for ContactHistory or some such.  As you continue documenting your contacts with a customer, you'll upgrade him from Lead to Prospect.  You'll also have a table structure to track your orders, and when you get an order you'll upgrade the customer from Prospect to Customer.

Therefore, you could perhaps simplify your design by adopting the business rule that a person that you have contacted is a prospect, and a person that has placed an order is a customer.  That might work for you and it might not; it doesn't deal with a lead that you contact and find out that he is deceased, for example.  You'll want to have some way of saying that the lead is a "dead" one, i. e. not going to turn into a prospect.  (If you use the CustomerType field, you'll probably want to come up with a category that handles this situation.)